# Javascript -> CSS (display:none to display:block)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 divs + 3 hidden divs. I want to click on "service1" and edit "display:block" in "toggle1".

The HTML:

```
<div id="service1" onclick="changeService('toggle1')></div>
<div id="service2"></div>
<div id="service3"></div>
<br><br>
<div id="toggle1"></div>
<div id="toggle2"></div>
<div id="toggle3"></div>
```

The CSS:

```css
#toggle1, #toggle2, #toggle3 {display:none}
```

The Javascript:

```
function changeService(this) {
    this.style.display = "block";
}
```

Hope I explained myself well enough so you guys can understand. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be best to use CSS classes.

So go:

```
#toggle1, #toggle2, #toggle3 {display:none}
#toggle1.active, #toggle2.active, #toggle3.active{display: block}
```

And then:

```
function changeService(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("class", "active");
}
```

Then you can **keep view and logic separated** and easily add more style if necessary. Try never to change your CSS in Javascript. Better add classes like this to keep things clear.

https://jsfiddle.net/t74tmu7r/2/

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Thanks to you and some more research I'm getting where I want https://jsfiddle.net/lordfox/n4dn9jur/
Now, I just need some way to find any "toggle active" div, and IF one is found, setAttribute("class", "toggle hidden"). But I will formulate another question for it.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a string into function, not an object. You can use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) method to get corresponding div element:

```
function changeService(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: didn't work. you put "id" as an example or is that really id?

Comment: ok, I got it to work! thanks to you! :) BTW, why if I put "id" it works, and "this" does not?

Comment: Because `this` is a reserved word, and it can't be used in such context.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the explanation! Will put right answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

first of all place your script file before the closing body tag to make sure all DOM elements are loaded then use this code:

```
function changeService(id){
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.style.display = "block";
}
```

then in the div tag with a class name 'service1' do this:

```
<div id="service1" onClick="changeService('toggle1');"></div>
```

that should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Thanks to you and some more research I'm getting where I want jsfiddle.net/lordfox/n4dn9jur Now, I just need some way to find any "toggle active" div, and IF one is found, setAttribute("class", "toggle hidden"). But I will formulate another question for it.